# Question-creep norms

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

Re: [How do I pass properties to stateless/functional components?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43919688/438992)

(To reiterate, I truly don't care my answer wasn't accepted and never brought it up.)

The original question was limited in scope. Either answer addresses those concerns. The question changed as the OP's lack of ES6 and/or JSX knowledge were exposed. I viewed (and view) the *new* question(s) as out-of-scope and should have been a new question.

(Technically I don't even think it should be a new question since it's pretty well-documented and I provided an explanatory link in one of my comments.)

Instead I was taken to task for not continuing the (IMO) off-topic tangent regarding a lack of ES6/JSX knowledge, which raised my ire because I viewed it as an almost complete lack of initiative on the asker's part, which I have low tolerance of, and it gets me a little angry/depressed. That's on me.

Once a question morphs beyond the original scope should users be encouraged to ask a new question, or is a change in scope on-topic for a single question?

My opinion is that it should be a new question, and that this was the SO norm. Have these norms changed? I don't keep up on meta very much these days, so it's quite possible it could have changed.

Comment: Normally I just walk away.  If they have follow up questions they can ask a new question.

Comment: @NathanOliver But they didn't ask a new question, they updated their existing question with the new problem (despite having it addressed in comments, and then the other guy rolled it into his answer). Although it also wasn't complete; the OP's issue with my non-destructuring answer led down the "Oh I don't know ES6" path. Which is why I'm wondering what the current policy is.

Comment: Read more about [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Chameleon, that's it; I couldn't remember what to search for. Thanks.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The sad part is I have an answer on it :/

Comment: So, ask the question.  And post the answer.  You probably won't get into a lengthy back-and-forth with the asker, that's a win.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah I lost this one :/

Answer (score 2):

At *each* step of solving a problem, you start over at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), either mentally or by actually reading it. This has the additional bonus that you might even solve the problem yourself without having to ask the question to begin with.

If you do decide to ask a question, and an answer helps you one step further, you accept it and go research the new problem that arises.

Of course an answer could contain a compile or implementation error, so you can use comments to verify erroneous behavior of the code. That's why it's important that an answer contains an explanation as well, so you can verify both as the asker and as a later visitor, that the assumptions made in the answer apply to your situation, and that you can implement the solution any way you like, without literally copy-pasting the answerer's code.

Answer (score -16):

IMO if its relevant information and its not a duplicate.  The back and forth may help other people get up to speed who also had the same original question.

If you feel your work is done on a post shouldn't you just let it be?

I find when I ask a specific questions I get lots of answers that are off tangent but still help me develop a broader understanding.

Comment: "Shouldn't you just let it be?" -- that's what I'm asking; are we supposed to point out that new questions should be new questions (e.g., "Oh, I see, but now I don't know *this*, which is a totally separate thing"), or did SO change policy on scope-creep.

Comment: My issue with the phrase "relevant information" is that there's a shit-ton of "relevant information" to almost every single technical question. In this case the "relevant information" is ES6, about which numerous tutorials, including those in a ReactJS context, exist, which would *also* make the question OT because the OP showed zero initiative in resolving their problem. And openly *admitted* as much, which I find exasperating and exhausting.

Comment: And on the last part, if answers are wildly divergent, it just adds noise to the question. Developing a broader understanding is *great*, but SO is for answering fairly specific, directed questions. No downvote from me, but I think I more or less disagree with everything you said ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton You shouldn't refuse to downvote content that you feel isn't helpful.  Feedback on the quality of posts is important.

Comment: @Servy Understood; on meta I tend not to downvote much unless it's egregious. Here I just disagree with everything, e.g., it's really just opinion :/ I dunno.

Comment: @DaveNewton So use your vote to reflect that opinion.  It's what they're for.

Comment: @Servy It makes me feel bad, and it's already been a bad-enough day.